# Getting Cookie from external app in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, spring, cookies

I have two projects in local, one is using PHP (port: 80) and other Javas Spring + AngularJS (port: 8080).
With the first project I'm authenticating users and creating cookies (TOKEN and USERNAME). Now, with the second app I need to get TOKEN and USERNAME but AngularJS return undefined.

Anyone knows whats happening?

**EDIT 24/11/2014:**
This is my indexController, I'm trying to get username to show in scope.

```
var cavControllers = angular.module("cavControllers", ['ngCookies']);
cavControllers.controller('indexController', function($http,$rootScope, $cookieStore, $cookies){
    $rootScope.title="Agora Voting";
    $rootScope.username = $cookieStore.get('username');
    console.log($cookieStore.get("username"));
});
```

Comment: Something goes wrong. To get more precise answer show us your code at least.

Comment: I have edit my question with my angular code.

Comment: For God’s sake what the name with a buck (`$http`) does in javascript?

Comment: First thing u should do is open browser debug and look if u indeed have that cookie.

Comment: yes, now Im getting cookie using spring and returning to angular using an method. But I need do it without call API